# Utilize multi-core with LocalMRJobRunner for MRJob

Tags: python, mrjob

I am using the python yelp/mrjob framework for my mapreduce jobs. There are only about 4G of data and I don't want to go through the trouble of setting up Hadoop or EMR. I have a 64 core machine and it takes about 2 hours to process the data with mrjob. I notice mrjob assigns 54 mappers for my job, but it seems to run only one at a time. Is there a way to make mrjob run all tasks in parallel with all my cpu cores?

I manually changed number of tasks but didn't help much.
`--jobconf mapred.map.tasks=10 --jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=10`

EDIT:
I have `-r local` when I execute the job, however, looking at the [code](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/blob/master/mrjob/local.py#L33), it seems it defaults to run one process at a time. Please tell me I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local job runner for mrjob just spawns one subprocess for each MR stage, one for the mapper, one for the combiner (optionally), and one for the reducer, and passes data between them via a pipe. It is not designed to have any parallelism at all, so it will never take advantage of your 64 cores.

My suggestion would be to run hadoop on your local machine and submit the job with the `-r hadoop` option. A hadoop cluster running on your local machine in pseduo-distributed mode should be able to take advantage of your multiple cores.

See this question which addresses that topic: [Full utilization of all cores in Hadoop pseudo-distributed mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357296/full-utilization-of-all-cores-in-hadoop-pseudo-distributed-mode)

Comment: Thanks, I hope to run hadoop in docker then.

Answer (score -1):

The runner for a job can be specified via the command line with the `-r` option.

When you run a `mrjob` script from the command line, the default run mode is `inline` which runs your job on your local machine in a single process. The other obvious options for running jobs are `emr` and `hadoop`.

You can make the job run in parallel on you local machine by setting the runner as `local`

```
$ python myjob.py -r local
```

Those `--jobconf` options are only recognised by Hadoop (i.e. on EMR or a Hadoop cluster).

Comment: I actually used `-r local` when running the command, however, I found it still execute the tasks serially. Looking at the document, it says `Local mode now runs 2 mappers and 2 reducers in parallel by default.`, but I can't figure how to alter the default.

Comment: OK sounds like the behaviour has changed. The few times I have used it in the past it has locked up my machine while the job runs because it uses *all* the CPU, so it makes sense that they would limit this behaviour.