# How to Best Run Hadoop on Single Machine?

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, virtual-machine, processing-efficiency, linux-containers

I have access to a computer running Linux with 20 cores, 92 GB of RAM, and 100 GB of storage on an HDD. I would like to use Hadoop for a task involving a large amount of data (over 1M words, over 1B word combinations). **Would pseudo-distributed mode or fully distributed mode be the best way to leverage the power of Hadoop on a single computer?**

For my intended use of Hadoop, experiencing data loss and having to re-run the job because of node failure are not large issues.

[This project](https://ofirm.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/creating-a-virtualized-fully-distributed-hadoop-cluster-using-linux-containers/) involving [Linux Containers](https://linuxcontainers.org/) uses fully distributed mode. [This article](https://github.com/jweese/thrax/wiki/Pseudodistributed-hadoop) describes pseudo-distributed mode; more detail can be found [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation).

Comment: GPU-level parallelization (e.g., using CUDA) might offer a better alternative for a single machine.

Comment: @vefthym I'm not familiar with GPU-level parallelization. What sources would you recommend looking at to become more familiar with it?

Comment: I am not a CUDA expert, myself, but I think that this is a good starting point: https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp I just provided this information, in case you find it useful. Have a look

Comment: @vefthym Okay thanks! I've got to consider the focus I want to take: learning Hadoop by using it or choosing whatever strategy will make my software run faster.

Comment: @vefthym I've decided to stick with Hadoop. So the scope of this question does not extend beyond Hadoop.

Comment: Please share the memory details also. I can update my answer with memory allocation

Comment: @AmalGJose I updated my question with memory details.

Comment: If you ask me, I think hadoop is the wrong tool for the give case. I think 'spark' would offer you better efficiency, flexibility for the given configuration. (and probably scaling out perspective)

Answer (score 11):

As per my understanding, you have a single machine with 20 cores. In this case no need of virtualizing it, because the VMs that you create will consume some resources from the total resources. The best option is to install Linux OS in the laptop, install hadoop in pseudo distributed mode and configure the available resources for container allocation.

You need CPU cores as well as memory for getting good performance. So 20 cores alone will not help you. You need good amount of physical memory also. 
You can refer this [document](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.1/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html) for allocating memory.

The fundamental behind hadoop is distributed computing and storage for processing large data in a cost effective manner. So if you try to achieve multiple machines in the same parent machine (small machines) by using virtualization, it won't help you because lot of resources will be consumed by the OS of individual machines. Instead if you install hadoop in the machine and configure the resources properly to hadoop, the jobs will execute in multiple containers (depending upon the availability and requirement) and hence parallel processing will happen. Thus you can achieve the maximum performance out of the existing machine.

So the **best option** is to set up a **pseudo distributed cluster** and allocate resources properly. Pseudo distributed mode is a mode in which all the daemons run in a single machine.

With the hardware configuration that you shared, you can use the below configuration for your hadoop set up. This can handle enough load.

```
(yarn-site.xml)    yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb  = 81920
(yarn-site.xml)    yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 1024
(yarn-site.xml)    yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 81920
(yarn-site.xml)    yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 16
(yarn-site.xml)    yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores = 1
(yarn-site.xml)    yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores = 1
(yarn-site.xml)    yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores = 16
(mapred-site.xml)  mapreduce.map.memory.mb  = 4096
(mapred-site.xml)  mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb   = 8192
(mapred-site.xml)  mapreduce.map.java.opts  = 3072
(mapred-site.xml)  mapreduce.reduce.java.opts   = 6144
```

Comment: Please update your answer now that I included memory and storage specs.

Comment: How did you come to that configuration? Did you run `python yarn-util.py <options>` to do so?

Comment: No. It is calculated based on the values given by you. You have 92 GB RAM. NN, RM, DN, NM, HS each need a min of 1 GB heap size. I reserved 4 GB for OS and left some memory free for other services. So totally I allocated 80 GB memory for processing. So 80 GB can be used for container allocation. So it can request for a max of  80 GB from the node. 4 GB and 8GB will be fine for Map and reduce heap size (It can handle enough load).. Like this I calculated

Comment: Doesn't the storage space also play a role in configuring correctly?

Comment: The configuration totally depends on the kind of jobs that you are running and the size of data. The configs I shared will work with large data. Simply storing the data in the disk doesn't matter. But the size that you process at a time matters.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Why 16 max VCores?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85306/discussion-between-amal-g-jose-and-ast).

Comment: Please check the chat.

Comment: Could you address data replication and node failure with respect to fully vs pseudo distributed mode?

Comment: In Pseudo distributed cluster, you have only one datanode and the replication factor will be one. So if that datanode fails, the data will be lost. This is the problem with single machine cluster. Fully distributed mode works with multiple machines, so multiple datanodes. So we can put higher replication factor. So the chances of data loss in case of a node failure will be less.

Comment: In light of that, do you still think that pseudo distributed mode is the best option for my situation?

Comment: In your case you have only one machine. So you cannot run multiple datanodes unless you create VM's inside that machine. Even if you create multiple VMs, all the VMs are running in the same parent machine. So if the parent machine fails, everything will fail. This doesnt make sense. The best choice for you is pseudo distributed cluster only. If you are much worried about the data that you are processing, you can specify a multiple locations  in the datanode directory configuration. You can keep one as a mount drive. But this may reduce the performance .

Comment: Okay thanks for the info! Do you recommend setting `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb` and `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts` according to the doc you linked?

Comment: You can run it with the default value. It will work. If you face any issues, increase the value

Comment: Running a test Mapreduce job after doing the config from your answer, total time spent by all map tasks went down from 3399 to 3275, but total time spent by all maps in occupied slots went up from 3399 to 13100. Why do you think this is?

Answer (score 4):

You lose all of the benefits of Hadoop when you are on a single machine. Yeah, you could use containers or VMs but there is no need. A  <strike>single</strike> standalone node instance with MapReduce with 20 mapper/reducer slots will perform better that a fully distributed cluster running on a single machine.

UPDATE: Using pseudo-distributed mode may be better at using all of the cores during M/R job. Apparently, standalone runs in a single java instance which probably isn't ideal for your use case.

Comment: By 'single node instance' do you mean pseudo-distributed mode?

Comment: No, I mean the "Standalone Operation" mode which is the default.

Comment: Though pseudo-distributed may be better for using all 20 cores.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a reference you could provide a link for where I could learn more about configuring it for standalone operation to have 20 slots? Because the Apache tutorial for setting up a single node cluster does not mention an option for specifying number of slots.

Comment: I have looked at that tutorial but it doesn't say anything about specifying the number of mapper/reducer slots... Any other links?

Comment: I think I found another SO question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357296/full-utilization-of-all-cores-in-hadoop-pseudo-distributed-mode

Comment: Could  you elaborate on why there is no need to use containers or VMs?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to utilize all the cores is
**Method 1:** to use virtualization if the hardware supports (install esxi or any of the hypervisors ) and create the VM instances of linux machines or install openstack cloud and create VMs so that you can  fully utilize the hardware.
**Method 2:** Though this can be achieved by a easier method of installing a host OS on a machine and installing VMware or Virtualbox,but as there is two layers b/w hardware and the hadoop performance is little reduced compared to the **Method 1**.

after this you can install the hadoop flavour you like.

Its always better to use distributed mode because in pseudo distributed mode there is a chance that data loss in case of crash of the system as the replication factor is 1 whereas in distributed mode the replication factor by default is 3.
And as in the pseudo distributed mode each deamon spins up with one java thread even a loss in single thread may cause entire MR job to run again.

Edit:
Looking at the configuration of storage of 100 gb and almost equal memory(assuming data is less than 100 gb) you can go ahead with pseudo cluster and u can leverage the advantage of in memory processing using **Spark** as  spark supports mapreduce equalent operations along with SQL, dataframes,mllib,graphX (Python is also comes natively), or if u know R u can directly use R using spark 1.4 (as spark is faster than hadoop)

Comment: My question asks specifically about whether fully distributed or pseudo-distributed mode would be better. Could you address that?

Comment: For my application of Hadoop, data loss and having to re-run the job are not an issue. In light of that, could you provide another argument for pseudo vs fully distributed mode?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Can I also leverage the advantage of in-memory processing using Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can leverage the real benefits of Hadoop considering you have only one machine in your cluster. In my opinion, an easier and better alternative would be to:

1. Please go ahead with Pseudo distributed mode and store your data in Hadoop.
2. Use any in memory database (**Impala or Presto or Spark**) on top of the data stored in hadoop.
3. Impala syntax is exactly the same as hive and you won't have to make any extra changes on your data for querying. Alternatively you can use Spark ML Lib for machine learning related tasks.

Comment: This answer does not address the question. Please revise it.

Answer (score 0):

Go for fully distributed mode hadoop cluster on vmware esxi platform, if your hardware supports. It seems to be the best way to exploit your resources

Comment: Can you add details/explanation for why that would be the best way to use my resources?

Answer (score -1):

"**fully distributed mode**" is a perfect choice where one can take full advantage Hadoop framework.

Comment: Could you make this answer more specific?

Comment: With respect to your scenario which involves processing of large amount of data, There may be chances of container/vm failures during computation. Since you'll have a fully distributed mode environment - where several roles in the ecosystem are distributed among different containers/vms, the probability of a job being successful will be high as the framework restarts the failed tasks.

Comment: Specifically, why would processing a large amount of data cause container/vm failures?

Comment: It is not necessary that there will be a failures all time. But considering a generalized scenarios that failures may occur, may be there is some noise in the dataset, or misconfiguration in the cluster, etc..,

Comment: Okay. Couldn't I still keep a high job-completion probability with pseudo-distributed mode?

Comment: If we consider, Why processing a large amount of data cause failures, then we can ignore the data replication considering that this is a brand new machine, it won't fail and I don't need replication.  But this is only an ideal situation. FAILURES can occur, we have to be ready to face them, to prevent loss of information.

Comment: Understood. But is there not a replication factor in pseudo-distributed mode also?

Comment: In pseudo-distributed mode - You'll be running hadoop on  a single machine, where  data is not replicated. Also it limits parallel  processing  capability.

Comment: Pseudo-distributed mode is running Hadoop daemons as separate processes on a single node/machine. Since you have only one node, data is not replicated physically. Even thought your hadoop runs, NN warns that there are under-replicated blocks.